# Not updating data on json file but my code is correct via PHP

Tags: php, json, web

I'm a newbie here so please be with. I'm pretty sure that my code and syntax is correct.

This is my json file

```
{"data":
    [
        {"label":"Signed-in Client","value":2
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my php code

```
<?php


    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","something");
    $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_pet_owner ORDER BY pet_owner_id");
    $max1 = mysqli_num_rows($res1);

    $jsonString = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $data1 = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    foreach ($data1['data'] as $key ) 
    {
    if ($key[0]['label'] == "Signed-in Client") 
        {
            $data1['value'] = $max1;
        }
    }
    $newJsonString = json_encode($data1);
    file_put_contents('data.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

but when I refresh, it doesn't update with the max count of my query. I hope you'd help me. This is for my thesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is connected with the way how you traverse the data.

For example in `foreach ($data1['data'] as $key )`, `$key` is already an associative array (e.g., `array("label" => "Signed-in Client", "value" => 2)`), so instead of `$key[0]['label']`, one should use just `$key['label']`.

Also, when you want to modify the `'value'`, one has to access the same associative array, not the original variable `$data1`.

One way to achieve this would be as shown below. In that example the array `$data1['data']` is traversed using references (`&$key`). Note that one should then unset this variable after the `foreach` block to break its association with the last element of the array being traversed.

```
<?php  
    $max1 = 100;//just an example

    $jsonString = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $data1 = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    foreach ($data1['data'] as &$key )
    {
        print_r($key);
        if($key['label'] == "Signed-in Client")
        {
            $key['value'] = $max1;
        }
    }
    unset($key);
    print_r($data1);

/* gives:
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Signed-in Client
                    [value] => 100
                )

        )

)


*/
    //$newJsonString = json_encode($data1);
    //file_put_contents('data.json', $newJsonString);
?>
```

Comment: i tried using your way of traversing the data's and it actually made a difference. But, the output was: 

{"data":
[ {
  "label":"Signed-in Client",
  "value":2
 }
]
 ,"value":7}

Comment: @JohnMarvicDianco are you sure that you are using `$key['value']` instead of `$data1['value']`?

Comment: Omy God, Sorry for my stupidity, I didn't obey your code about the $key['value'] because I thought that it will not pass the data to $data1. I tried it and it was a charm. But I can't process it to my mind how it happened. Thank you! Every commend that I can make, I'll give it to you. :))))))

Comment: no problem :) `$key` is a reference (thanks to the ampersand in `&$key`) to a particular element of the array being traversed so any changes are "reflected" directly in the original array...